# Print Java Results to multiple locations

Tags: java, html, maps

I got a scripts that convert google locations to google coordinates (lat/lng) and that works great.

My results are printed to a table with td and tr. Till now, everything works good. 
But i want to print the results (The coordinates) also to another location in HTML.

I want that the results also printed to a table in XXXX. Optional also the location...

It is not working for me...

```
 function getResultsListItem(resultNum, resultDescription) {
        var html = '<a onclick="selectMarker(' + resultNum + ')">';
        html += '<div class="info" id="p' + resultNum + '">';
        html += '<table><tr valign="top">';
        html += '<td style=""><img src="' + getMarkerImageUrl(resultNum) + '"/></td>';
        html += '<td style="">' + resultDescription + '</td>';
        html += '</tr></table>';
        html += '</div></a>';
        return html;
    }

    /**
     * Get suggestions for a postcode with multiple localities.
     * @param {!google.maps.GeocoderResult} resultDescription Geocoding result.
     */
    function getPostcodeLocalitiesSuggestion(resultDescription) {
        if (resultDescription.types.indexOf("postal_code") == -1) return "";
        console.log(resultDescription.postcode_localities.length + " localities");
        var postcode = resultDescription.address_components[0].long_name;
        var html = '<span class="dym">Did you mean</span>: ' + '<span class="pc_localities">' + postcode + ' in ';
        for (i in resultDescription.postcode_localities) {
            var locality = resultDescription.postcode_localities[i];
            html += '<a href="#' + escape(getPermalink(postcode + ' ' + locality)) + '">';
            html += locality + '</a>';
            html += (i == resultDescription.postcode_localities.length - 1 ? '.' : ', ');
        }
        return html;
    }

    /**
     * Get a nicely formatted result description.
     * @param {!google.maps.GeocoderResult} result Geocoding result.
     */
    function getResultDescription(result) {
        var bounds = result.geometry.bounds;
        var html = '<table class="tabContent">';
        html += tr('Address', result.formatted_address);
        if (result.postcode_localities) {
            html += tr('Localities', result.postcode_localities.join('<br/>'));
        }
        html += tr('Types', result.types.join(", "));
        html += tr('Location', result.geometry.location.toString());
        html += tr('Bounds', (bounds ? boundsToHtml(bounds) : "None"));
        html += tr('Viewport', boundsToHtml(result.geometry.viewport));
        html += tr('Location type', result.geometry.location_type);
        if (result.partial_match) {
            html += tr('Partial match', 'Yes');
        }
        html += '</table>';
        return html;
    }
```

The HTML with location and name...

```
 <table width="90%" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Foto: *</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="file" id="bestand" name="bestand">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Boxname: *</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id="boxname" name="boxname">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>User: *</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Country: *</td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="categorie" id="categorie">
                                        <option value=""> - Gelieve een Land te kiezen - </option>

                                            <option value="<?php echo $categorie['categorie_id']; ?>">
                                                <?php echo $categorie['naam']; ?>
                                            </option>

                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Location: *</td>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea id="location" name="location"></textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td>Coordinates: *</td>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea id="coordinates" name="coordinates"></textarea>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" id="knop" name="knop" value="Add New Suezbox">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Comment: I think if you use JSP, it will be easier as just importing the object and printing the info with expressions.

Comment: Maybe, but i didn't find a solution for this. I think it's possible with a simpel javascript...